# как сделать чтобы левая панель и текст не вылезал

Tags: html, css

как сделать чтобы левая панель и текст не вылезал :http://front-endlabs.000webhostapp.com/lab4/html/Kvasnuk_exercise1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У элемента `#menuVertical ul li a` строго прописана ширина в пикселях..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за этого оно и вылезает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение**

Изменить `width: 198px` на `width: 100%`.

Comment: а с текстом который тоже вылезает что делать?

Comment: @dadadasda вам там вообще надо вёрстку переделать

Comment: никак нельзя исправить?

Comment: Не наблюдая проблем с использованием решения - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/nLlTcZl.png)

Comment: @dadadasda исправить это надо переделать этот сайт весь полностью